# Bathroom exhaust fan through clay tile roof

Tags: roof, vent, ducts, exhaust-fan, flashing

I've installed an exhaust fan in an upstairs bathroom and need to vent it through the clay tile roof. (pic attached)

[image]

The standard 4" pipe jacks and flashings I'm finding at Home Depot don't seem to be designed for clay tiles and are too small/stiff to conform to the shape.  Example: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Master-Flow-4-in-Roof-Jack-with-Wagon-Cap-RJWC4/100140997

I can't seem to find much information online about how to vent a bathroom fan through this type of roof.  Any ideas / links to products?

Comment: Do everything in your power to not penetrate a roof, especially a clay tile one. Go out the wall. "Tile roofing is one of the more complicated pitched-roof systems to deal with" –[solarprofessional.com](http://solarprofessional.com/articles/design-installation/tile-roofing-systems-materials-and-methods-for-flashing-penetrations/page/0/2) I'd redo all the drywall in your bathroom before I had to do work on that roof.

Comment: Despite the points made by @Mazura you should look closely at all the rest of your roof and the roofs with similar tiles in your area to get an idea if any roof vents are ever done. And if they are used then get an idea of how it is done.

Comment: Are there any other roof jacks there already? As others, I'd strenuously avoid a new hole in that roof.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The other upstairs bathroom does have an exhaust fan that vents through the roof.  I took a peek and it looks like it uses a vent with a large soft base to conform to the tile.  Similar to [this](http://www.bestmaterials.com/detail.aspx?ID=9713).  Possibly a secondary flashing underneath the tile too.  I'm having a roofing guy come out today so we'll see what he says.

Comment: By any chance do you have a brand name for your roof tiles? They are identical to mine... I've been searching in order to do repairs but have been unsuccessful. Any help would do!! Thank you so much!